# How to draw multiple rectangles FLTK C++

Tags: c++, fltk

I am trying to create a program in fltk and I followed this example

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(340,180);
  Fl_Box *box = new Fl_Box(20,40,300,100,"Hello, World!");
  box->box(FL_UP_BOX);
  box->labelfont(FL_BOLD+FL_ITALIC);
  box->labelsize(36);
  box->labeltype(FL_SHADOW_LABEL);
  window->end();
  window->show(argc, argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

from [FLTK docs](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html). The problem is I'm trying to draw multiple rectangle shapes to the window and it seem very tedious to create multiple boxed in order to have multiple rectangles. I tried looking up a lot of tutorials on drawing shapes on FLTK but I can't find anything simple enough to show me.

My code looks like this so far

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Widget.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
// #include <FL/fl_draw.H>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(900, 600);
    window->position(0, 0);
    window->color(FL_BLACK);
    window->end();
    window->show();
    while (1) {
        int ev = Fl::event();
        if (ev == FL_SHORTCUT) {
            if (Fl::event_key() == FL_Escape)
                break;
        }
        Fl::check();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I would like to implement the drawing inside the loop (continuously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an important side note: You should really consider using `Fl::run()` instead of your custom while loop, I ran into many problems with a similar approach like yours.

Now, to answer your question:

Take the example and wrap the Box creation inside a loop. You can take for example an index for assigning different positions to each Box.

```cpp
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(340,500);

   // 3 Fl_Boxes in a loop
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
       Fl_Box *box = new Fl_Box(20, 40 + i*120, 300, 100,"Hello, World!");
       box->box(FL_UP_BOX);
       box->labelfont(FL_BOLD+FL_ITALIC);
       box->labelsize(36);
       box->labeltype(FL_SHADOW_LABEL);
   }
   window->end();
   window->show(argc, argv);
   return Fl::run();
}
```

You control the layout with the formula `20, 40 + i*120, 300, 100` in the box Constructor. You have to adjust that to your requirements.

With FLTK one basic rule is: All widgets you initialize between the window constructor and `window->end()` or any other widget that works the same way, for example `Fl_Group`,  will become children of the surrounding element and will show, if their parent is shown.

I am not entirely sure, if `Fl_Box` is what you are looking for. I found [Erco's FLTK Cheat Page](http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/) extremely helpful. You might find inspiration and other approaches to your problem there.

Comment: Oh the reason for using a custom loop is, I'm creating a dynamic library which will not have a main and will be used via `dl_open`.

Comment: So isn't there another way I could draw multiple rectangles  apart from `Box`?

Comment: @SASSY_ROG Yes. In a custom canvas like in [this example](http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk/#FltkScrollingCanvas) just with rectangles instead of diagonal lines.